# Moving down an aligned environment

Tags: align, environments

I have a quick question. Here is my code:

```
So in particular, one can compute that \begin{aligned} D\tilde{F}_i(s,t) &= \begin{bmatrix} 
\partial_s F_1 &  \partial_t F_1\\
\partial_s F_2 & \partial_t F_2 \\
\partial_s F_3 & \partial_t F_3
\end{bmatrix} \\

&= p
\end{aligned}
```

And here is what it looks like:

[image]

While I want it to look like this:

[image]

I know this is something minor but I'm not really familiar dealing with environments yet!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some errors in your code. First, `aligned` is an "internal" form which must be used within math mode; second, you cannot leave empty lines in math mode. TeX tries to recover, and the result is the strange mixture of text and math fonts you show. Your code issues dozens of errors: never ignore them.

After correcting these errors, in order to align the top line of `aligned` you can simply use the `[t]` optional parameter.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

So in particular, one can compute that
$
\begin{aligned}[t]
D\tilde{F}_i(s,t)
&= \begin{bmatrix} 
  \partial_s F_1 & \partial_t F_1\\
  \partial_s F_2 & \partial_t F_2 \\
  \partial_s F_3 & \partial_t F_3
  \end{bmatrix} \\
&= p
\end{aligned}
$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I get where it went wrong, but this is perfect! :)

Comment: @Arthur I'd suggest to use a display, rather than inline math.